# Find the derivative of the question mentioned

Tags: calculus

Question: find the derivative of
$$
  x^3\cdot y^7+\frac{x}{y}-x^2+y^4=3
$$
I got
$$
  \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy^2-y-3x^2y^9}{4y^5+7x^3y^8-x}
$$

Comment: Am I correct? Thank all!

Comment: Hey again Bellasmili  T, since you've been posting quite a bit today you should check out http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

It will help you format the math portions of your question. Using LaTeX or mathjax, you can make something like dy/dx x^n look like $\frac{dy}{dx}x^n$

Comment: @BellasmiliT I took the liberty of formatting the mathematics in your question for the sake of clarity. Please make sure that my edits were correct (that I interpreted what you wrote correctly).

Comment: How did you get that result? Did you use implicit differentiation on the original equation? Did you multiply the equation to get rid of the fraction before differentiating? Or something else? There are multiple valid methods which will give valid answers that look quite different from each other.

Comment: I re-edited the format again:) however, thank you graydad, mapierce271 and Daulton so much!

Comment: sorry for I didn't know how to toye

Comment: Sorry for I didn't know how to type the equation by this method^^"

Comment: I got the same result, modulo the order of terms in the numerator/denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using implicit differentiation you get $$3x^2y^7+7x^3y^6y'+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{xy'}{y^2}-2x+4y^3y'=0 \\ \implies y'\left(7x^3y^6+4y^3-\frac{x}{y^2}\right)-2x+3x^2y^7+\frac{1}{y}
=0 \\ \implies  y'\left(7x^3y^6+4y^3-\frac{x}{y^2}\right) = 2x-3x^2y^7-\frac{1}{y} \\ \implies y' = \frac{2x-3x^2y^7-\frac{1}{y}}{7x^3y^6+4y^3-\frac{x}{y^2}}$$ and it is clear if you multiply through by $\frac{y^2}{y^2}$ you get exactly the result you posted in your question. Looks good!